# Unable to remove app role assignments using Graph API. Getting "EntitlementGrant being updated or deleted is not found." error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created some app roles for my Azure AD application and assigned a user in those roles. Using Graph API, I can list the app role assignments just fine.

Request URL:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<my-application-id>/appRoleAssignedTo`

Here's the response I get (partial for the sake of brevity):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('<my-application-id>')/appRoleAssignedTo",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "<app-role-assignment-id>",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appRoleId": "<my-application-role-id>",
            "createdDateTime": "2021-04-16T00:50:28.7061339Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "User Name",
            "principalId": "<user-id>",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "<my-application-name>",
            "resourceId": "<my-application-id>"
        },
...
```

However when I try to delete an app role assignment, I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "EntitlementGrant being updated or deleted is not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-20T15:08:28",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Request URL for delete:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<my-application-id>/appRoleAssignedTo/<app-role-assignment-id>`.

I am not sure what does this error message mean:

> EntitlementGrant being updated or deleted is not found.

Would appreciate if someone can explain this to me.

I found another question with exact same issue - [Microsoft Graph API: EntitlementGrant being updated or deleted is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124844/microsoft-graph-api-entitlementgrant-being-updated-or-deleted-is-not-found) but that is marked as closed as not reproducible (which is surprising because it is certainly reproducible.

BTW, removing app role assignment from Azure Portal also does not work. Removing a user app role assignment is consistently failing with `Microsoft.Online.DirectoryServices.DirectoryValueNotFoundException` in the Azure Portal.

**UPDATE**

I get the following error messages in the audit logs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? You said that it cannot be deleted in the portal?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5hWq.png

Comment: “Remove” button is enabled but when I click on it, I get an error that the operation failed.

Comment: It's weird, I just deleted it in the portal without errors. Let me test this api and wait for my good news.

Comment: @CarlZhao - Thanks. Updated my answer and included the screenshots of the error messages in the audit logs.

Comment: I believe it is a bug caused by the migration from `App roles | Preview` to `App roles`, for the same users, same app roles, all the old assignments not work, all the new assignments work fine.

Comment: @JoyWang - Thanks. Can you tell me when did this migration happen? I started using this functionality very recently only. I believe this is an issue with the service itself. Please see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-serviceissues/issues/60. Let's keep this open for next few days. After that we will close it as "Service Issue".

Comment: I didn't pay attention, but should no more than one month.

Comment: @JoyWang - Then I don't think it is the same problem as I started using it very recently (just last week).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Joy said is absolutely correct. I have also tested this several times in Azure portal and MS graph api. I found a rule that all the old assignments not work, all the new assignments work fine. So, I also think it is a bug caused by the migration from `App roles | Preview` to `App roles`.

Currently, if you want to delete the old assignments, you can only delete the Enterprise Application and then create it again. (You delete the Enterprise Application will not delete the application in App registrations).

[image]

Refresh and create again:

[image]

---

**Add:**

It is a bug caused by the migration from `App roles | Preview` to `App roles`. This is an bug of Azure AD itself. I have reported the error message to Microsoft, and Microsoft should resolve it as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate how would you differentiate between "old assignments" and "new assignments"? How old is old or how new is new? In my case the role assignment was done on 16th of this month only. Would you consider that old?

Comment: @GauravMantri  I'm not sure on the specific day, if you add an assignment now, you should be able to delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that adding a new assignment and deleting it works immediately works just fine. Let me try by deleting the enterprise application and start from scratch.

Comment: I can confirm that after deleting and recreating enterprise application, I am able to delete role assignments properly. Thanks for all your help @CarlZhao!

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. So yesterday I was able to delete role assignment however when I tried to do it just now, I got the same error as above. Only difference I can think of is that I have obtained an access token for the user for my API resource.

Comment: @GauravMantri  Let me test it.

Comment: @GauravMantri  I just used Azure portal and ms graph api to delete the role I just add. So, are you saying that you cannot delete a role that was added yesterday or a role that was just added today?

Comment: I can’t delete the role assignment I added yesterday.

Comment: Tried to delete the role assignment again just now (thinking that an active access token might be preventing the deletion). Still no luck :(. Getting the same error.

Comment: @GauravMantri  This is really an unfortunate thing. Can you give me one day time? I have assignment some roles today, I will try to delete it tomorrow and give you feedback.

Comment: Absolutely Carl! Please take your time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @GauravMantri  I think this has nothing to do with tokens, I still think this is a Microsoft bug!

Comment: @GauravMantri  I just did a test and can delete the roles assigned yesterday.

Comment: @GauravMantri  You can now try to delete it.  See if it works！

Comment: Yes, I can delete it now :). Thanks for all your help. It is very much appreciated. Can you also edit your question and include something about this being an issue with Azure AD itself? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, I have added it to the answer :)